# Output wrong div width by width() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a popup with bootstrap to store several Social media share buttons. Then I created two left and right buttons to navigate between them.  My logic is, **if modal-body width is less than share buttons content div width, then navigation buttons should be appeared and move to the very end in both sides**. Here, in my code, I'm **getting wrong modal-body width** and therefore right-side navigation button is not working as expected which is **I can't go to  the last share button**. It seems perfectly working with the default loading screen size. **The Problem can be exactly seen by reducing the screen size and trying to navigate to the last share button**. What I missed here?

```js
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
   var currentPos = 0;
   var shareBtns = $(".a2a_kit a").length;
   var sampleDivWidth = $(".a2a_button_facebook span").width();
   var actualButtonWidth = sampleDivWidth + 26
   var shareDivWidth = (actualButtonWidth * shareBtns) / 3;
   var mainDivWidth = $(".modal-body").width();
   //var mainDivWidth = 445;

   var x = shareDivWidth / actualButtonWidth;
   var y = mainDivWidth / actualButtonWidth;
   var z = (x - y);
   var stopPos = z * (-actualButtonWidth);

   //alert(mainDivWidth);

   if( (mainDivWidth - 30) < shareDivWidth ) {
    $(".move-btn").css("display", "block");
   }
   else {
    $(".move-btn").css("display", "none");
   }
   if ( currentPos === 0 ) {
    $(".move-btn-l").css("display", "none");
   }

   $(".move-btn-r").on("click", function() {
    $(".a2a_kit").animate({
     left : ""+ (currentPos -= 66) +"px"
    }, 200);
    $(".move-btn-l").css("display", "block");
    
    if (currentPos <= stopPos) {
     $(".move-btn-r").css("display", "none");
    }
   })

   $(".move-btn-l").on("click", function() {
    $(".a2a_kit").animate({
     left : ""+ (currentPos += 66) +"px"
    }, 200);
    $(".move-btn-r").css("display", "block");

    if (currentPos == 0) {
     $(".move-btn-l").css("display", "none");
    }
   })

  })
```

```css
.share-link-div{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
 }

.a2a_kit {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
 }

 .a2a_kit a .a2a_svg {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: none !important;
 }

 .a2a_kit a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
 }
  
   .move-btn{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #7d7d7d;
 }

 .move-btn-r {
  right: 15px;
 }

 .move-btn-l {
  left: 15px;
 }

 .move-btn span{
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: absolute;
 }
  
   .embed-btn .a2a_svg {
  float: left;
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
 }

 .embed-btn .a2a_svg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
 }

 .embed-btn .a2a_svg p {
  margin: 0px;
  top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
 }
  
  .embed-src{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
 }
  
   .embed-button{
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
 }

 .embed-button .embed-src {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
 }
  
  .copy-iframe {
    border-radius : 0 4px 4px 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>




<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
        <div class="share-link-div">
      <div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
       <a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_pinterest"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_pinterest"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
       <a class="a2a_button_pinterest"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="move-btn move-btn-l">
       <span>&lt;</span>
       <!-- <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i> -->
      </div>
      <div class="move-btn move-btn-r">
       <span>&gt;</span>
       <!-- <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> -->
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="embed-button">
      <div class="embed-src">
       <span>URL and Code</span>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary copy-iframe">Copy</button>
     </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the editable code :**

http://jsfiddle.net/rgL2ak0z/3/

Comment: you can use `.css('width')` instead of `.width()`

Comment: .css('width') returning 0px as the Div width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cant get width of dynamicaly created div without prior width initialization. Maybe you could get width of document and calculate it? Like:

var mainDivWidth=document.documentElement.clientWidth;

Comment: Good idea. Thank you!